# How do I get more guns?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, you can collect guns. These guns can replace the default in-game guns. They do not change gameplay at all, and are purely cosmetic.

How can I get new guns?

Comment: @Retrosaur Good job pointing that out, but I'm pretty sure I asked my question first... The time I posted this was probably around 1AM - 3AM.

Comment: @Retrosaur Ah. I messed up then :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the new "Arms Deal" update which went live yesterday (14/08/2013).
Valve released a really good FAQ on it, which can be found [here](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/faq.php).

The bits of interest for your particular question, "how can I get new guns?":

- Timed weapon drops, just by playing on official and community servers in any game mode.
- Opening dropped weapon cases with a weapon case key.
- Trade weapons with other players through Steam's Trading interface.
- Purchase them from other players through the Steam Marketplace.

Regarding the first point, these are obtained for play time over the course of a week. As your play time increases, the drop rate will slow down. This is reset when the week rolls over. Not sure the start day or time of a week though.

I'm not 100% sure where you will get the weapon case keys. The below quote suggests that you buy these:

> This update will also actively support the CS:GO competitive community with the introduction of the eSports Weapon Case. A portion of the proceeds from sales of eSports Case Keys will go towards prize purses at competitive events.

Hope that helps.