# At what rate do weapons drop in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What are the CS:GO weapon drop rates? Does the drop chance on an achievement idle server go down if you're idling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly, the system has changed and idling won't get you items, something I have observed to seem true in the game. I don't think you will ever get the formula, it is a secret and information won't leak because weapons can be monetized.

Related / Duplicate : [How do I get item drops?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127591/how-do-i-get-item-drops)

[Valves's FAQ linked in the above answer](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/faq.php)

Edit : I forgot to mention it but the drop rates go down over time, if you have like X % chance to drop an item per game, it will decay and reset to X % at the end of the week. This ensures people don't spend too much time farming weapons, or find new ways to idle, probably.

Answer (score -1):

Not going to lie, I was idling last week and still got item drops so it does still give you items, just not as often.

Comment: It would be good if you could back your answer up with some evidence.